# Solve $f'(x)+\int_{\pi/4}^{x}f(t)dt=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, trigonometry

So far what I have is that I set $F(x)=\int_{\pi/4}^{x}f(t)\,dt$ so that the equation satisfies $F(x)+F''(x)=0$, and I have $F(0)=-\int_{0}^{\pi/4}f(t)\,dt$ and $F'(0)=f(0)$.

From there, I was able to get $$\int_{\pi/4}^{x}f(t)\,dt=\sin(x)f(0)-\cos(x)\int_{0}^{\pi/4}f(t)\,dt$$
and determined that the zero function was a solution, but I have no idea how to solve for everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiating the initial identity you get $f''+f=0$. So $f(x)=a\cos x+b \sin x$ for some constants $a$ and $b$. Now you can compute explicitly:
$$
f'(x)+\int^x_{\pi/4}f(t)\,dt=-a\sin x+b\cos x+a\sin x-\frac a{\sqrt2}-b\cos x+\frac b{\sqrt2}=0,
$$
which gives $a=b$. So $f(x)=a(\cos x+\sin x)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** instead of $0$, why don't you use $\frac{\pi}{4}$ as the "base point"? Solving the differential equation in $F$, you get $$F(x) = A\cos x + B\cos x$$
 and it remains to find the constants. But then $F(\frac{\pi}{4}) = 0 = A\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+B\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$; and similarly $F^\prime(\frac{\pi}{4}) = -A\sqrt{2} = f(\frac{\pi}{4})$...