# Find all differentiable functions for which $f'(x)+\int_{\pi/4}^x f(t)dt = 0 $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

I am having trouble knowing when I have found *all* possible functions $f(x)$ for the equation. How can I be sure I have found every single one? The question is:

> Find all differentiable functions $f(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}$ that satisfy the equation
>   $$f'(x)+\int_{\pi/4}^x f(t)dt = 0 $$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solve $f'(x)+\int_{\pi/4}^{x}f(t)dt=0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1633769/solve-fx-int-pi-4xftdt-0)

Comment: @Jonas I don't think this is a duplicate, since the focus of the question is about making sure that all solutions have the desired form.

Comment: @T. Bongers What desired form (other than the complete set of solutions given in the other post)?

Comment: @Jonas The question seems to be about how to prove that all solutions are of the form given in the linked post - but neither of the answers do that.

Comment: Differentiate the equation, This leads to an ODE to be solved. This introduces two arbitrary constants. Put the solution into the original integral equation in order to keep only the valid solutions.

Comment: What you ask for is immediate: the integral is a $C^2$ function...

Comment: This can be solved with Laplace Transforms too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is a solution to your problem, then $f'$ is equal to the opposite of the antiderivative of $f$ which is supposed to be continuous. Therefore $f$ is of class $C^2$, and we can differentiate to get

$$f''+f=0.$$

From basic results about differential equations, you get that there exists $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that

$$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}, \;f(x)=a\cos(x)+b\sin(x)$$
(I am assuming $f$ is real valued; otherwise use $e^{\pm ix}$ instead)

Now, using the original equation with $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$, we have $f'(\frac{\pi}{4})=0$, which leads to $a=b$. Therefore
$$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}, \,f(x)=a(\cos(x)+\sin(x)).$$

Reciprocally, it is easy to check that any function of this kind is a solution.

In other words, the set of solutions is a 1-dimensional vector space whose basis is $\cos+\sin$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint

Differentiate the equation with respect to x, then solve the differential equation

Comment: How do you know $f \in C^{2}$?

Comment: @Mattos Notice that by rearranging, $f'$ is equal to the integral of a function with continuous derivative. This gives $f \in C^2$ (and by repeating, $f \in C^{\infty}$).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about how to be sure that **all** solutions have been found. It gives a technique to find solutions, but how does it guarantee all of them?